# WordPress/ACF: get_category(); for parent category

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, advanced-custom-fields, wysiwyg

I am using an [ACF Wysiwyg Editor field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/wysiwyg-editor/) in order to be able to write some extra text for my category pages. I am echoing the text using category.php

At first I thought I could just echo out get_field but found out that I need to pass in the category. Therefore I've used get_the_category(). But for some reason code only works for child categories:

example.com/category/parent/child/ <- works
example.com/category/parent/ <- doesn't work

I've also tried with wp_get_post_categories(); but no luck. What am I missing ??

```
<?php

$category = get_the_category();

$extra_text = get_field('ekstra_tekstfelt', $category[0] );
?>

<p> <?php echo $extra_text ?></p>
```

I've tried print_r($category) where both child and parent category gave me an array:

**Child category**

```
Array ( [0] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 27 [name] => Tilbehør [slug] => tilbehor [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 27 [taxonomy] => category [description] => [parent] => 1 [count] => 31 [filter] => raw [cat_ID] => 27 [category_count] => 31 [category_description] => [cat_name] => Tilbehør [category_nicename] => tilbehor [category_parent] => 1 ) )
```

**Parent category**

```
Array ( [0] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 46 [name] => Bagværk [slug] => bagvaerk [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 46 [taxonomy] => category [description] => [parent] => 1 [count] => 16 [filter] => raw [cat_ID] => 46 [category_count] => 16 [category_description] => [cat_name] => Bagværk [category_nicename] => bagvaerk [category_parent] => 1 ) [1] => WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 16 [name] => Dessert [slug] => dessert [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 16 [taxonomy] => category [description] => [parent] => 1 [count] => 22 [filter] => raw [cat_ID] => 16 [category_count] => 22 [category_description] => [cat_name] => Dessert [category_nicename] => dessert [category_parent] => 1 ) )
```

Comment: First thing to notice, is that you should use `get_field()` instead of `the_field()` here, since `the_field()` actually echoes immidiatly, so it is not used when you are trying to save a variable. also - `get_the_category` is missing its `()` and is normally used on post objects - you could try to use `get_queried_object()` to try to get the category object.

Comment: also - are you sure that the parent cat has the field filled out? and is it using the same cat file? or is it using archive.php?

Comment: Thank you, Stender. My appologies. I was using get_field and get_the_category();... get_queried_object broke site and gave me error. I've just tried with a simple echo on the category.php and it came out on both the parent and child cat. Yes, the parent cat has the field filled out.

Comment: Figured out why get_queried_object(); was breaking site... Since I was using $category[0] - Deleted [0] and it gave me same result: works for child category but not parent.

Answer (score 0):

Going through your code, it seems to be fine but need to check whether we are getting values for every variable or not, whether the acf fields are empty or not?

Below is the example from official site of ACF. In your code, you can make sure you are getting proper object of second argument you are passing.

```
 // get the current taxonomy term
 $term = get_queried_object(); // or other way where you get the category term object
 // example
 $image = get_field('image', $term);
 $color = get_field('color', $term);
 echo $color;
 echo $image;
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried with get_queried_object(); but same result... Works for child category but not parent :/

Comment: Try to print the object. are you getting the object with proper data?

Comment: In your code , try to print `$category` for child category and parent category

Comment: both are giving me an array... I've updated question :)

Comment: I would request to give a try like this `$taxonomy . '_' . $term_id`.   For example `category_123`, instead of passing the term object

Comment: `$taxonomy  =  'category';  $term_id ="12";  get_field('ekstra_tekstfelt', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id );` $term_id is the category id in your case and $taxonomy is the taxonomy slug. $term_id will be dynamic

Comment: that seems to make it work for parent page! And yeah... term_id should be dynamic since now the field from the parent category is being displayed on all the categories :)